# Setting Windows env vars via azure-pipelines.yml + script

Tags: windows, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

Following Azure [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#script) yaml documentation the `script` stanza (not sure of YAML terminology sorry) should be able to set environment variables.

I am finding adding a Windows job, my Python code is not seeing the environment variable. Is this [PR](https://github.com/facebookincubator/ptr/pull/32/files) doing it correctly? Full azure-pipeliens.yml can be found [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/ptr/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml)

- Also now my MacOS job has stopped running the `ci.py`

I suspect I'm doing something wrong, *any* pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I can see now printing the environment I'm setting: $(CI.ENV): 1
- Need to see if I can resolve the variable name somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `- script` stanza can not resolve variables from a matrix. Statically name your environment variable and the value can be resolved from a variable.

Change:

```
$(ci.env): '1'
```

to

```
'CI_TYPE': '$(ci.env)'
```